Can the Lookup_range and result_range of an X-Lookup refer to a column name (column_name) instead of the column range(A:A)?
hoping an excel wizard see's this and can help me. I want to do an Xlookup[XLOOKUP(search_key, lookup_range, result_range)] but instead of defining the lookup_range and result_range as 'A:A' for instance, I want to use the column name (e.g. Column_One). My data will always have the same header - but won't always be in the same column, unfortunately. Any ideas?

Excel questions are off-topic on Web Apps but on-topic on [su]

Formatting your range as a structured table is far and away the easiest way to do this, as @Reddy Lutonadio indicated. If you're a masochist, you can also use the INDEX function with two MATCH functions, one to look up the row from your column of values to search, then the second one to look up the column of interest from your row of headers. Ex:
INDEX(data_range, MATCH(search_key, lookup_range), MATCH(result_header_name, headers_range))
This is, strictly speaking, how I would do what you asked if you don't use structured tables, but unless there is a very good reason you can't, make your life easier and use them. They will handle renaming and rearranging columns all day.

If you format your range as table, then you can use the table's header as shown on the example below.
=XLOOKUP(C11,Table1[City],Table1[Country],,0)

The headers are used for the lookup and return arrays.

